# Android Getting coordinates of an image

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have a custom `ImageView` that re positions a an image on a web page. The image that is seen on the phone screen should represent the image on the web page.

I am using `Matrix.mapPoints(float[] dst, float[] src)` to try and get the how much the image is off-set when scaled to correctly frame the image. I am also taking into account the how much the image is scaled, and the size if the image view on the phone compared to the image tag width on the web page.

**UpdateImage() in Image view class**

```
public void updateImage() {
      final float phoneDisplayScale = (float) getWidth() / (float) getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();

      float[] m = new float[9];
      matrix.getValues(m);

      float scale = m[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
      float[] arr = {0, 0};
      matrix.mapPoints(arr, arr);

      //holder.rect = {image_x, image_y, imageWidth, imageHeight}

      if (holder != null) {
        holder.getRect()[0] = arr[0] / phoneDisplayScale;
        holder.getRect()[1] = arr[1] / phoneDisplayScale;
        holder.getRect()[2] = scale * (getImageWidth() / phoneDisplayScale);
        holder.getRect()[3] = scale * (getImageHeight() / phoneDisplayScale);

        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: " + Arrays.toString(holder.getRect()));
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: " + Arrays.toString(holder.getRect()));
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: " + Arrays.toString(holder.getRect()));
      }
      //
      //   
      // Socket io code
      //   
      //

}
```

this works when the image is scaled and aligned to so that the top left of the image is in the top left of the `ImageView`, but you can never zoom in on the bottom right of the image. I also noticed that if I zoom in to the max that the map points method returns the width and height (minus values) of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my logic was a bit off I have changed the position calculation to the following and it now works.

```
holder.getRect()[0] = (arr[0] / scale) * phoneDisplayScale;
holder.getRect()[1] = (arr[1] / scale) * phoneDisplayScale;
```